# Pandas warn_bad_lines=False and error_bad_lines=False is still trying to parse bad lines

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to import a tsv file. One of the lines is bad and I don't know which one. I'd like pandas to just ignore that line. This does not work:

```
bob_date_parser2 = lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%m/%d/%Y")  #"3/7/2013"
df = pd.read_csv(fname, sep="\t", parse_dates=['country_release'], date_parser=bob_date_parser2, encoding='utf8',
                 warn_bad_lines=False, error_bad_lines=False)
```

I know my file handling is correct, since I can just `head` the first lines and import with no problems. However, when I try my entire file `read_csv` fails with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "interpret_data_parse/wrangle_survey_data.py", line 57, in <module>
    main()
  File "interpret_data_parse/wrangle_survey_data.py", line 51, in main
    print load_master_interpret_boxoffice()
  File "interpret_data_parse/wrangle_survey_data.py", line 35, in load_master_interpret_boxoffice
    warn_bad_lines=True, error_bad_lines=False)
  File "/home/isl/rfcompton/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 420, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/home/isl/rfcompton/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 225, in _read
    return parser.read()
  File "/home/isl/rfcompton/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 626, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "/home/isl/rfcompton/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1122, in read
    names, data = self._do_date_conversions(names, data)
  File "/home/isl/rfcompton/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 946, in _do_date_conversions
    self.index_names, names, keep_date_col=self.keep_date_col)
  File "/home/isl/rfcompton/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1948, in _process_date_conversion
    data_dict[colspec] = converter(data_dict[colspec])
  File "/home/isl/rfcompton/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1915, in converter
    return generic_parser(date_parser, *date_cols)
  File "/home/isl/rfcompton/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/date_converters.py", line 38, in generic_parser
    results[i] = parse_func(*args)
  File "interpret_data_parse/wrangle_survey_data.py", line 33, in <lambda>
    bob_date_parser2 = lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%m/%d/%Y")  #"3/7/2013" wtf
TypeError: must be string, not float
```

I'm on pandas 13.1

Comment: Perhaps try the date parsing after reading the csv?

Comment: @AndyHayden that's probably what's going to happen. However, I was under the impression that error_bad_lines was designed to prevent that.

Comment: Or put a try/except block in the parser. This may be a bug, you should post bug reports on github: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/new :)

Comment: error_bad_lines is used when there are too many or too few of the delimited fields. It will not handle datatype errors as far as I know. I am not completely sure but it seems like you error is that you have a number in your date field where pandas and your date parser is expecting a string.

Comment: @grromrell I went through the file and found a blank entry in the date field. They should rename *_bad_lines to *_wrong_number_of_columns

Comment: @AndyHayden https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6478